# Javascript odd performance special in V8

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, v8

Today I have written few line of JS and I was stunned.... Maybe I miss something but can't figure it out.

Situation is as follow. I have a function which is called twice (or even more times). The first execution of function is faster than following executions.

Code was tested in Node & Chrome (V8 engine)
Firefox is executing the code each time at fixed speed, which is quite slower than V8 Engines. Whatever different execution speed across the engines are not important. The question is about why function first execution is faster than others in V8.

Here is the code: (It can be copy/pasted in chrome console and you will see the result)

```
var loop = 10000000;

function callable() {
    return Math.random();
}

function measureFunction(index) {
    var result = 0;
    var timer = new Date();
    var start = timer.getTime();
    for (var i = 0;  i < loop;  ++i)
        result += callable();

    res[index] = "RESULT FUNCTION: " + result + " FOR: " + (new Date().getTime() - start);
}

var res = new Array(2);

for (var i = 0  ;i < res.length;  ++i)
    measureFunction(i);

for (var i = 0;  i < res.length;  ++i)
    console.log(res[i]);
```

Comment: When I run the code in Node, the results are almost exactly the same every time. Sometimes the first one is faster, sometimes the second. The amount of work the program is doing is so small that the times don't really mean much.

Comment: on my CPU (Atom Z3775) first time execution is for around 120ms and then the function goes for around 150ms+. Could it be because of CPU?

Comment: CPU and other factors. For times around 100ms and below, operating system activity can have a significant impact, and the system timer used with the Date API is not really very accurate. Try `100000000` instead of `10000000` (10x more).

Comment: I was running the above code many, really many times and the result is always the same...second time is slower. I tried with 10x input and time is 10x slower :)

Comment: I use the 10x as input, first will always get faster at about `200ms` than second on chrome or nodejs. And Both of them are significantly faster than on `IE11` or `firefox`.

Comment: I use Node.js v5.0.0, and there is no difference. They are almost the same

Comment: i was trying with node 4.2.2. Hm... going to see which version of V8 is used in both version

Comment: @KamenStoykov 4.2.2 has 4.5.103.35 and 5.0.0 has 4.6.85.28. But even 4.2.2 gives me similar result only

Comment: The issue seems reproducible here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7ahgsdv6/ in several browsers.

Comment: @jfriend00: I cannot reproduce, neither in Chrome46 nor Opera12. Constantly runs in about 1040ms (+-70)

Comment: @Bergi - in Chrome 46 on Windows 8.1, I get run times of 3465,3528, 3536, 3540, 3533, 3535, 3540, 3541, 3540, 3533.  The first one is consistently lower than the others.  In Firefox 42 on Windows 8.1, I get run times of 224, 248, 249, 226, 243, 247, 248, 249, 242, 244 which still has the fastest time as first, but does have one other time(the 4th) that is similar and the rest are higher.

Comment: I personally cannot reproduce either. However I did experience a similar behaviour when running a much more CPU-intensive task (enough to make the CPU fan doubling speed): the first execution is faster, as if the next ones were throttled or CPU down-clocked… Idling for 1second or so was enough to make next executions as fast as the first one. But in the case of jfriend00's fiddle, removing the setTimeout does not change the performance on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: it's because of the GC. But it's complicated.

I've reproduced your observation with a debug build of `V8 version 4.8.0 (candidate)` (the one I've had handy) on this slightly modified js:

```
var loop = 10000000 * 10;

function callable() {
    return Math.random();
}

function measureFunction(index) {
    var result = 0;
    var timer = new Date();
    var start = timer.getTime();
    for (var i = 0;  i < loop;  ++i)
        result += callable();

    res[index] = "RESULT FUNCTION: " + result + " FOR: " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + " ms";
}

var res = new Array(3);

for (var i = 0  ;i < res.length;  ++i) {
    measureFunction(i);
    print (i + " COMPLETE"); // use console.log for node
}

for (var i = 0;  i < res.length;  ++i)
    print(res[i]); // ditto
```

It gives the following output on my machine:

```
0 COMPLETE
1 COMPLETE
2 COMPLETE
RESULT FUNCTION: 49997528.61602645 FOR: 649 ms
RESULT FUNCTION: 49996578.63860239 FOR: 1402 ms
RESULT FUNCTION: 49995279.39097646 FOR: 1400 ms
```

After that I've run the v8 shell with the following options: `d8 main.js --trace-opt --trace-deopt --trace-gc`

And it gave the following output (abridged):

```
    ...
[marking 0xaaf9fce2a79 <JS Function measureFunction (SharedFunctionInfo 0xaaf9fce2501)> for recompilation..
[didn't find optimized code in optimized code map for 0xaaf9fce2501 <SharedFunctionInfo measureFunction>]
[compiling method 0xaaf9fce2a79 <JS Function measureFunction (SharedFunctionInfo 0xaaf9fce2501)> using Crankshaft OSR]
[optimizing 0xaaf9fce2a79 <JS Function measureFunction (SharedFunctionInfo 0xaaf9fce2501)> - took 1.092, 3.601, 2.595 ms]
[didn't find optimized code in optimized code map for 0xaaf9fce2501 <SharedFunctionInfo measureFunction>]
[optimizing 0xaaf9fcd2181 <JS Function random (SharedFunctionInfo 0xaaf9fc5c111)> - took 0.445, 2.367, 0.122 ms]
[completed optimizing 0xaaf9fcd2181 <JS Function random (SharedFunctionInfo 0xaaf9fc5c111)>]
[deoptimizing (DEOPT eager): begin 0xaaf9fce2a79 <JS Function measureFunction (SharedFunctionInfo 0xaaf9fce2501)> (opt #3) @14, FP to SP delta: 120]
            ;;; deoptimize at 298: wrong instance type
    ... 
[deoptimizing (eager): ... took 0.099 ms]
Materialization [0x7ffffae625a8] <- 0x25c6de07d439 ;  0x25c6de07d439 <Number: 5.00034e+07>
[removing optimized code for: measureFunction]
[evicting entry from optimizing code map (notify deoptimized) for 0xaaf9fce2501 <SharedFunctionInfo measureFunction> (osr ast id 71)]

0 COMPLETE

[marking 0xaaf9fce2a79 <JS Function measureFunction> for recompilation, reason: small function, ICs with typeinfo: 13/15 (86%)...]
[14386:0x49c5fb0]      657 ms: Scavenge 2.1 (37.1) -> 1.2 (37.1) MB, 1.2 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
[didn't find optimized code in optimized code map for 0xaaf9fce2501 <SharedFunctionInfo measureFunction>]
[compiling method 0xaaf9fce2a79 <JS Function measureFunction (SharedFunctionInfo 0xaaf9fce2501)> using Crankshaft OSR]
[optimizing 0xaaf9fce2a79 <JS Function measureFunction (SharedFunctionInfo 0xaaf9fce2501)> - took 1.232, 5.863, 0.621 ms]
[didn't find optimized code in optimized code map for 0xaaf9fce2501 <SharedFunctionInfo measureFunction>]
[14386:0x49c5fb0]      667 ms: Scavenge 2.1 (37.1) -> 1.2 (37.1) MB, 0.7 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
[14386:0x49c5fb0]      668 ms: Scavenge 2.2 (37.1) -> 1.2 (37.1) MB, 0.4 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
[14386:0x49c5fb0]      669 ms: Scavenge 2.2 (37.1) -> 1.2 (37.1) MB, 0.4 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
[14386:0x49c5fb0]      669 ms: Scavenge 2.2 (37.1) -> 1.2 (37.1) MB, 0.4 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
[14386:0x49c5fb0]      670 ms: Scavenge 2.2 (37.1) -> 1.2 (37.1) MB, 0.4 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
... and so on, 1550 times ...

1 COMPLETE

Same thing (only the scavenger messages) for 2.
```

The situation changes if I supply, for example, `--gc-interval=1` to v8. In this case Scavenge and Mark-sweep GC cycles happen during the first call as well and the output looks like this:

```
0 COMPLETE
1 COMPLETE
2 COMPLETE
RESULT FUNCTION: 50005046.56689139 FOR: 919 ms
RESULT FUNCTION: 50006871.86618896 FOR: 678 ms
RESULT FUNCTION: 49998279.72474023 FOR: 670 ms
```

**UPD**

It turns out eljefedelrodeodeljefe is partially right.

Let's see what happens.

measureFunc starts off unoptimized. It gets hot very quickly so Crankshaft optimizes it and an OSR entry is performed (execution continues where it left off -- from the middle of the loop -- but on the newly optimized version of machine code). But for some reason shortly after that a speculative assumption is broken, causing a bailout (OSR exit to unoptimized, 'full' code).

And V8 doesn't try to recompile measureFunc again before the first call ends.
Probably because it already OSRed into optimized function and a speculative assumption failed, so it sees no point in eager retrying (I suppose. I don't know what heuristics are used exactly).

So most of the time the first call of measureFucntion is executed on the Full-compiler tier. And this full code doesn't seem to trigger GC while it's running in the loop. I don't know if it's intentional or a bug. It's a subject to a further investigation.

So yes, the first call execution is (mostly) unoptimized and the subsequent executions are optimized. But V8 doesn't decide to run the code slower. The first execution happens to be faster because the unoptimized code doesn't stop to trigger GC. And it makes real difference in this example, because the code is actually GC-intensive (due to a lot of heap number allocations with short life-time).

Comment: But why doesn't GC run in the first iteration as well? What is different there? Also: What garbage does the code create that makes collection necessary?

Comment: @Bergi, the garbage is the random number. I'll try to answer the rest later

Comment: Ah, I thought the random numbers would go on the stack…

Comment: @Bergi, yeah, Math.random allocates them on the heap and returns a boxed value

Comment: So only in the second run the heap limit is reached and GC kicks in? And with half the iterations, the first two runs would be fast?

Comment: @Bergi, that would be my guess too. I won't be able to check this until tomorrow, since I don't have a v8 build on this computer.

Comment: @Bergi, nope, it was not a correct guess. See the updated answer. BTW, thanks for asking and pushing me further to seek out the truth :). Kamen Stoykov, you are welcome )

Answer (score 1):

There can be many things wrong with this code. However two things are likely:

1. V8 has actually two compilers and on top garbage collection. In the second run probably it decides to do full compilation or to have done GC. So calling constructors in performant code is maybe not a good idea
2. V8 optimizes or de-optimizes your code based on lots of rules. When you run `node --trace-deopt main.js`, there are definitely deopts happening. On second run V8 decides tu run your code slower, for some reason.

Note that if you split your code up into two separate functions the second function will even run faster.

You could investigate more with the `node --v8-flags` options.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot let this question die without a real answer!

The problem is that V8 doesn't like converting "result" to a string implicitly via the polymorphic "+" operator.

If you explicitly convert result from a Number to a String, expected performance is restored.

```js
res[index] = "RESULT FUNCTION: " + result + " FOR:
// ===>
res[index] = "RESULT FUNCTION: " + Number.prototype.toString.apply(result) + " FOR:
```

You can tell from looking at --trace-deopt output.  Performing the explicit conversion changes the deopt from an "eager" unrecoverable deopt to a "soft" deopt that is recoverable over time.

Likewise, you can see a MASSIVE difference in --trace-gc.  The original code generates many scavenges.  Using the explicit conversion results in only a single scavenge.

The end result is that optimal performance is achieved if you explicitly convert.